# How to use react-router 4.0 to refresh current route? not reload the whole page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

'react-router-dom' has refresh function [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v0.13.3/modules/createRouter.js#L435-L437), but I don't know how to call this method, also their [well formatted document](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Route/location-object) doesn't bother to explain this.

window.location.reload() doesn't work for me, because it wipes out the app store as well. I changed some data, and then need to reload the route with updated data.

I also read this:
https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/1982
https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/2243

this thread is exactly discussing my question:
https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4056

and still clueless how to do it. This basic function should not require too much effort, but after spending huge amount of effort, I can't reload current route.

here is my code:

```
@inject('store') @observer
export default class PasswordInput extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props)
        this.setPwd = this.setPwd.bind(this)
        this.submit = this.submit.bind(this)
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.case = this.props.store.case

        this.setState({refresh: false})
    }
    setPwd(e) {
        // console.log(e)
        this.case.pwd = e.target.value

    }
    submit() {
        console.log(this.props.caseId)
        this.setState({refresh: true})

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Container>
                <div>{this.state.refresh}</div>
                { (this.state.refresh) && <Redirect refresh={true} to={'/cases/' + this.props.caseId}></Redirect>}
                <br />
                <Grid columns="three">
                    <Grid.Row>
                        <Grid.Column key={2}>
                            <Form>
                                <label>Enter Password</label>
                                <input placeholder="empty"  type="text" onChange={this.setPwd} value={this.case.pwd}></input>                               

                                <Button name="Save" color="green" size="mini" 
                                style={{marginTop:'1em'}}
                                onClick={this.submit}>
                                    Submit
                                </Button>                               
                            </Form>
                        </Grid.Column>
                    </Grid.Row>
                </Grid>
            </Container>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: "refreshing" a route sounds like xy problem https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: You should probably create a jsfiddle for that. The component re-renders when the data it observes changes. Is that not happening.

Answer (score 14):

I solved this by pushing a new route into history, then replacing that route with the current route (or the route you want to refresh). This will trigger react-router to "reload" the route without refreshing the entire page.

```
if (routesEqual && forceRefresh) {
    router.push({ pathname: "/empty" });
    router.replace({ pathname: "/route-to-refresh" });
}
```

React router works by using your browser history to navigate without reloading the entire page. If you force a route into the history react router will detect this and reload the route. It is important to replace the empty route so that your back button does not take you to the empty route after you push it in.

According to [react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/1982) it looks like the react router library does not support this functionality and probably never will, so you have to force the refresh in a hacky way.

Answer (score 5):

You could use this little trick.
Push a new path in the history like **history.push('/temp')** and immediately call the **history.goBack()**

Here the example:

Create an history and pass it to the router:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

export const appHistory = createBrowserHistory();

<Router history={appHistory}>
  <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
  <Route path="/about" component={About} />
</Router>
```

then somewhere in your app, change the history:

```
appHistory.push('/temp');
appHistory.goBack();
```

In this way the route will "remain" the same, and will be refreshed.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem and I have no clue how the refresh does. My solution is to do following two steps.

1. push new path to history
2. reset all states

Then the DOM will rerender with your route.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I achieved it :

```
if (currentUrl == newUrl) {
    props.history.push("/temp");
    props.history.goBack();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if react-router already solved this issue but in my case. I make a new route with pathname refresh that go back when first time rendering the component

```
<Route
    path="/refresh"
    exact
    component={() => {
       useEffect(() => history.goBack(), []);
       return <></>;
    }}
 />
```

So when I want to refresh the route. I just push to refresh routes and then it go backs then rendering a new reload result;

Answer (score 1):

Only this worked for me:

```
reloadOrNavigate = () => {
  const { history, location } = this.props;
  if (location.pathname === '/dashboard') {
    history.replace(`/reload`);
    setTimeout(() => {
      history.replace(`/dashboard`);
    });
  } else {
    history.push('/dashboard');
  }
};
```

The answer is similar to the previous one but I needed to add `setTimeout` function in order to make it work. In my case, I had to refresh the current URL by clicking the logo if I'm on the `/dashboard` page. First, it goes to extra route `/reload` (the name is up to you) and then immediately returns. The page becomes white for less than a second and appears with reloaded data. No reloading in browser occurs, it is still SPA which is good.

Comment: While this might answer the question, you should [edit] your answer to include how your code answers the question, to provide context to future readers. A code block by itself is not immediately useful to those who might come across the same issue later on.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution with react-router-dom's "Redirect":

```
<Route key={props.notifications.key} path={props.notifications.path} exact render={() => <Redirect to={props.notifications.path + "/update"}/>}/>
<Route key={props.notifications.key + "/update"} path={props.notifications.path + "/update"} exact render={() => <props.notifications.component apis={props.notifications.apis}/>}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I used key and state to solve this in our app.

In my case, we want to refresh without fully reloading when clicking the same menu even though it is active already.

So, in our menu click, I have this code. It doesn't have to be uuid, it can be anything as long as it changes every time you trigger. It doesn't have to be an object with reloadKey prop too, it's up to you. It can be as simple as string only, I just coded it this way.

```
push({state: {reloadKey: uuid()}});
```

Then, I set the key in the Route.

PrivateRoute is my wrapper that wraps Route from react-router-dom.

```
const {state: { reloadKey } = {}}  =  location;
<PrivateRoute key={reloadKey} path="/path" component={Component} />
```

Because the key changed, this will trigger the component to re-mount and will not trigger a full page reload.

Answer (score 0):

All right, I have tried pretty much every answer before but nothing worked. This was the only way I could force a reload

I'm using redux but you could also use any state management you prefer

1 - Set a boolean to false

2 - Add an onClick function to your Link/button that will set the boolean true

3 - Add that boolean variable to useEffect()

This will trigger the re-render

```
useEffect(() => {
   // Do stuff...
},[forceReload])

const forceReload = () => {
   dispatch({ type: RELOAD });
   // OR useState or whatever you want
   setForceReload(true);
}


...
<Link onClick={forceReload} to="/my-path-that-does-not-reload">
   Reload Page
</Link>
```

That worked for me for the Link and HTML button tag

Answer (score 0):

I am using redirct at the beginning, which removes trailing slash from the end of the url

```
 <Redirect key={0} from="/:url*(/+)" to={pathname.slice(0, -1)} />
```

Then you can set your route path with trailing slash on the end and it will be reloaded every time.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that works for me.
https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/1982#issuecomment-305735126

```
 history.push(redirectUrl);
 history.go(0);
```