# React Router - Home component does not reload when click home link in home

Tags: reactjs, react-router, components, refresh, history

I have a simple react router with "/" rendering home component. I am in "/" which renders the home component. How do I get it to refresh when I click home link even though it is already in "/" ?

In context, think of YouTube, if I click the YouTube logo on the top left, it refreshes the page. Currently in my react project if I click the home link while at home, it does nothing.

```
const MainRoutes = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <NavBar />
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
      <Route exact path="/login" component={Login}/>
      <Route exact path="/post" component={Post}/>
      <Route exact path="/about" component={AboutRoutes}/>
      <Route exact path="/listing/:handle" component={Listing}/>
      <Route exact path="/mylistings" component={MyListings}/>
    </div>
  </Router>
)
```

Comment: refer this link -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47602091/how-to-use-react-router-4-0-to-refresh-current-route-not-reload-the-whole-page?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You can use an intermediate function to achieve this,

```
<Route path='/' component={()=><Home/>} />
```