# Handling react router with server

Tags: reactjs, server, react-router

I am using react router. Assume I am in `/dashboard` route.

Now if I refresh the page, request will go to the server. And server redirects to `/`. What happens here is, I am navigated to `/` route, instead of `/dashboard`.

What I want is, When I refresh the page, I want to navigate to the same route instead of navigating to `/`.

Can anyone help me in resolving this issue?

Comment: [possible answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51332885/5490517)

Comment: Your client needs to handle the fact that the app is being loaded from a non-root URL, please show at least your client router code.

Comment: @James I am just creating routes, I am not handling anything in the client. Can you tell me the way to handle the routes on the client-side? My routes look like this : 
<Router> <Switch> <Route path="/about" component={Help} /> <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} /> <Route path="/dayZero" component={Dashboard} /> <Route path="/" exact component={Login} /> </Switch> </Router>

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this is my production server configuration issue

we are redirecting "/" from the server for all get routes instead of sending the "index.html" file.